# Sync one video to another

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

The situation is like this - I have two videos, positioned on top of each other. These videos are almost the same (content wise), when you enter the page, video 1 starts playing. There is also a button, which when pressed should sync the second video to the first one and slowly fadeIn (it's hidden at first).

The problem I am having is with the syncing, when I try to set the currentTime of the second video, the player obviously first buffers some frames and after that starts playing, causing desync. I also tried some syncing timeouts with setting currentTime each 10ms until the second video's readyState turns to 4, but that causes pretty big delay.

The code I am using so far:

```
function switchVideo(first, second) {

    var currentTime = first.currentTime;
    second.pause();
    second.currentTime = currentTime;
    second.play();
    syncAllowed = true;

    var videoInterval = setInterval(function() {
        if(next.readyState >= 4) {
            second.addClass('show');
            syncAllowed = false;

            setTimeout(function() {
                first.pause();
            }, 500);

            clearInterval(videoInterval);
        }
    }, 100);
}

var syncVideos = setInterval(function() {
    if(syncAllowed) {
        second.currentTime = first.currentTime;
    }
}, 10);
```

So the question is, is there any way to sync one video to another one that is already playing, without having too much delay for the first video to get enought data for playing after setting it's current time? Also I noticed that there is a little bit of lag going backwards in time, which is weird, because that portion of video should already be buffered.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Just a side note - the syncing is not supposed to be persistent. Just long enough for the duration of the overlaying second video on top of the first one (fadeIn anomation) ~ 1-2 seconds.